# Structuremap constructor parameter injection convention

Tags: structuremap, convention

Is there a convention of specifying a value for constructor parameters named with "x". For example do something like below

For any requested dependency, having a constructor parameter named "pathToFile" , provide this value.

I could do this with `For` syntax and using `ctor` but cannot write same piece of code for every class that i want to get configured.

```
public class FileManager(string pathToFile):IDocumentManager
{

}
```

When ever i request IDocumentManager(dependency) it(instance) has a constructor with parameter named `pathToFile` so i want it to get injected with some value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create custom convention. Create convention by implementing `IRegistrationConvention`. Then in `Process` method check if type is concrete type, check if it has required constructor parameter and then register constructor's paremeter for all interfaces it implements and also type itself. I am using such convention to inject connection string.

```
public class ConnectionStringConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsConcrete() || type.IsGenericType) return;

        if (!HasConnectionString(type)) return;

        type.GetInterfaces().Each(@interface =>
        {
            registry.For(@interface)
                .Use(type)
                .WithProperty("connectionString")
                .EqualTo(SiteConfiguration.AppConnectionString);
        });

        registry.For(type)
            .Use(type)
            .WithProperty("connectionString")
            .EqualTo(SiteConfiguration.AppConnectionString);
    }

    private bool HasConnectionString(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetConstructors()
            .Any(c => c.GetParameters()
                .Any(p => p.Name == "connectionString"));
    }
}
```

After convention created, register it in your container configuration:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    x.TheCallingAssembly();
    x.WithDefaultConventions();
    x.Convention<ConnectionStringConvention>();
});
```

For more information check:

http://structuremap.github.io/registration/auto-registration-and-conventions/

http://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2010/06/04/teaching-structuremap-about-c-4-0-optional-parameters-and-default-values/